# public classG<A extends X & Y & Z> regarding generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, syntax, interface

I have the following statement in Java.

```
public classG<A extends X & Y & Z>
```

As this question requires knowledge about Java, I have assumed that `X`, `Y` & `Z` are all Java classes. But as far as I know, in Java, one class cannot extend multiple classes. Then what will be the correct assumption about `X`, `Y` & `Z` classes?  Are all they Java interfaces?

Comment: Take a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html. They're bounded types and all other types following the first bounded type must be interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `extends` clause in a bound type declaration may refer to a class the generic type extends or an interface it implements. If a class is present in the list, it must come first.
So, in other words, `X` may be a class or an interface, while `Y` and `Z` are interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't inherit from multiple classes so the answer will be probably :
X, Y, and Z are all Java interfaces